# Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer autenticação no banco de dados?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, .net, oracle, autenticação

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer uma conexao ao banco de dados utilizando c#?

Criar uma tabela USUARIOS, ou criar um USUARIO no banco de dados para acessar?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 3):

Não existe a melhor maneira. Existe a mais adequada para sua situação.

Se quer saber qual é a mais segura é usar a autenticação do banco de dados, ainda que outras formas podem ser bem seguras se fizer certo.

Mas nem sempre isto possível. Nem sempre é o desejado. Você pode:

- ter acessos anônimos
- ter uma quantidade muito grande de usuários
- permitir auto cadastro
- dar acesso a partes do banco de dados que não deveria

enfim, tem várias situações que não é o ideal, aí uma solução própria pode ser mais adequada.

Uma quantidade imensa de aplicações só faz sentido ter sua própria tabela de usuários, especialmente para web e mobile.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Entendi, estou fazendo uma aplicação Desktop c#, optei por autenticação no banco de dados em si, porem... (certeza que deve existir) uma forma de se manter uma conexão ativa com o banco até que o usuario saia da aplicação. Hoje eu abro e fecho a conexao em um simples select por exemplo. Existe alguma maneira? Ou qual o nome correto desse tipo de procedimento? Andei procurando por POOL mas nao obtive muito exito... Valeu

Comment: Pegar uma conexão é diferente de conectar no banco de dados.

Comment: especificamente, eu preciso manter a conexao do banco de dados ativa, e nao abrir e fechar simultaneamente varias vezes. Tudo que eu faço hoje, eu abro e fecho a conexao.
Obrigado por estar me ajudando, acima de tudo.

Answer (score 2):

Para o caso de autenticação de usuários eu uso 3 soluções dependendo do caso e do cliente;

1. Todos os usuários possuem um usuário próprio no sql: passo na *connection string* o usuário, assim é possível colocar mais um nível de segurança. Por exemplo, o usuário não pode ler tabela `x`
2. Todos os usuários tem registro no AD: Usuário padrão na *connection string* e faço a validação com o AD;
3. Bagunçado: Utilizo o [IdentityServer](https://identityserver.io/) (atualmente na versão 4) é mais complicado de implementar e normalmente vale apena se você tiver "vários sisteminhas" e quiser autenticar tudo em um lugar só; caso venha a ter mais sistemas tudo autentica no mesmo lugar

Comment: Muito Obrigado!